# ¿Como publicar un proyecto api .net con una librería de clases?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, net

tengo un proyecto api en .net pero decidí separar la lógica de los controladores de los modelos y todo lo relacionado con la BD (como en este video https://youtu.be/h9QKQa7NO7Q) y ahora necesito publicarlo en un servidor IIS ya el server lo tengo funcionando, lo probe con el api de ejemplo que genera el Visual Studio 2022 y corre bien. pero cuando publico el proyecto `ARC_CivControl` no anda y siento que es por que el proyecto es codependiente con `Domain` ***que es una libreria de clases***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuándo una solución tiene varios proyectos como el mío, cual es el debido proceso para publicar?

Comment: Es el mismo, verifica que las dll's existan en la carpeta de publicación. Además la imagen de tu pregunta cámbiala por una que tenga abierta la carpeta `dependencias` para verificar si el proyecto `Domain` está correctamente referenciado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por línea de comandos

1. Usa `cd` para ir hasta la raiz de la solución `ARC_CivControl`.
2. Ejecuta `dotnet publish -c Release`
3. Todo lo que debes deployer se encuentra en: `.\ARC_CivControl\bin\Release\net5.0\publish`

Por Visual Studio

1. Click derecho en el proyecto (No la solución)
2. Elige Publish...
3. Click en `Add a publish profile`
4. Escoge `Folder`. Next
5. Deja la opción por defecto que debe ser `bin\Release\net5.0\publish\`.
6. Click en `Finish` luego en `Close`
7. Se habrá generado el perfil de publicación. Presiona el botón `Publish`
8. Todo lo que debes deployer se encuentra en: `.\ARC_CivControl\bin\Release\net5.0\publish`

En cualquiera de los dos métodos el archivo `Domain.dll` debe de encontrarse también en esa carpeta.

Comment: Si esa es la solución, el mismo Visual Studio cuando uno publica compila el proyecto de biblioteca